# Instantiating a class via reflection using a constructor with a functional interface

Tags: java, reflection

If I have a class, that has a private interface inside, which has the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation, and a private constructor which takes an instance of a class that implements this interface, how can I construct this object using reflection with my custom implementations of the said interface? For instance:

```java
public class mcve {
  private mcve(mcve.wrapper<String> wrp1, mcve.wrapper<String> wrp2) {
    // ...
  }
  private mcve(mcve.wrapper<String> wrp1) {
    // ..
  }
  public static final mcve INSTANCE_1 = new mcve(ClassExtendsString::new, ClassExtendsString::new);
  public static final mcve INSTANCE_2 = new mcve(ClassExtendsString2::new, ClassExtendsString2::new);
  @FunctionalInterface
  interface wrapper<O> {
    O wrap(O object) throws Exception;
  }
}
```

and some code trying to accomplish what I want:

```java
 Constructor<mcve> constructor;
 constructor = mcve.class.getDeclaredConstructor(??.class);
 constructor.setAccessible(true);
 mcve testInstance = constructor.newInstance(?? MyCustomClassExtendingString::new);
```

How do I proceed? The compiler complains about `Object` not being a functional interface. I'm not sure what to pass to `getDeclaredConstructor` and `newInstance`.

Comment: Why would you use reflection here?

Comment: Assume I cant modify `mcve'.

Comment: @KamilaSzewczyk Why are you passing a `MyCustomClassExtendingString::new` ? You could have passed the object itself `new MyCustomClassExtendingString()`

Answer (score -1):

Ah.  You have to explicitly cast it to a `wrapper`:

```
mvce testInstance = constructor.newInstance((wrapper<String>) MyCustomClassExtendingString::new);
```

Comment: If `wrapper` isn't visible, then you have to go to some pretty ridiculous lengths to make this work: you'll need to write `MethodHandleProxies.asInterfaceInstance(Class.forName("com.whatever.mcve.wrapper"), MethodHandles.lookup().findConstructor(MyCustomClassExtendingString.class, MethodTypes.methodType(void.class, String.class)))`.

Needless to say, that's ridiculous, and you should really try to avoid reflection or extending String at all (?!).